# remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array: my code is throwing runtime error while submitting on leetcode but it gives right answer for all testcase?

Tags: c++, vector

Problem: remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array
My code:

```
class Solution {
public:

        int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
            int count = 1;
            auto remove_duplicate = nums.begin();
            auto check_duplicate = nums.begin()+1;
            while(check_duplicate != nums.end()){
                if(*check_duplicate != *remove_duplicate){
                    remove_duplicate++;
                    if(check_duplicate != remove_duplicate){
                        *remove_duplicate = *check_duplicate;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                check_duplicate++;
            }
            return count;
        }
    };
```

Error:

```
Line 851: Char 45: runtime error: applying non-zero offset 4 to null pointer (stl_iterator.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:860:45
```

Comment: You forgot to test with the empty vector.

Comment: your code seems to count, not remove. The names are rather confusing.

Comment: [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) would be an option.

Comment: maybe you can find a hint here: https://www.techiedelight.com/remove-duplicates-vector-cpp/